# How can run django tests in Pycharm Pro, getting ImproperlyConfigured and AppRegistryNotReady errors

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-testing, django-tests

I am having issues running django tests in PyCharm Pro.

1. I am able to run `python manage.py runserver` just fine.
2. I am able to `migrate`, `makemigrations`, `manage.py test` just fine. Actually, everything with `manage.py` runs as expected.

Whenever I run tests in PyCharm (by clicking the green run button), I get this error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

I have done several things to fix this:

1. I have, in my test file, put this:

   `import os
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'` (with `mysite` being the correct dir I promise)
2. I have a settings file and a wsgi file, and my wsgi file *does* set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE:

   `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")`

   `application = get_wsgi_application()`
3. The only thing that has taken me out of this error was by setting up the configuration for that test class by going to `Edit Configuations -> Environment -> Environment Variables` and adding the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` there. This only gets me a different error:

   `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

   Plus, I have to do this for **every** test class *and* I can't run individual tests in the class, but must rather run the entire test suite in that class. Not a good solution...
4. I have manually (in the virtualenv) run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`. This has not changed anything.

So, I am out of ideas and have followed all the advice I could find on SO. Is there something else I have to do in Pycharm? Again, the cmdline works fine, but I'd really rather not run tests this way - plus, I can't debug.

Edit: It may be worth noting that I am running the unit tests while my server is  running (this should not make a difference), and I am also have the python interpreter pointed to the one in my virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open the **Run/Debug Configuration window** (you should find it in the top toolbar, clicking the dropdown menu near the play / debug button and **Edit Configuration**)
From here, you should see a list with the existing saved configurations where the last element should be **Templates**. Search **Django tests** under Templates. In the environment part, add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` to the **environment variables**. The next time you'll run a test that is not existing in your run/debug configurations, the template with the setting module set will be used.

If I were you, I will delete all the existing test configurations. Also, I suspect from your point 3, that you have probably a python test configured instead of a Django test (this is why you had the error `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet` because Django was not loaded). If you have it, delete it too. Apply the configurations and retry to run the test.

When you run the test, ensure that a Django test is run, not a python one (you should see the Django logo near the test name in the run section and in the dropdown in the toolbar)